# Adding regex expression to accept particular pattern of input in textbox using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a text-box which accepts only numbers and having a pattern of 01-12-22, please help me to get the regex pattern.

Comment: Is this a date pattern?

Comment: As indicated by @Mindbreaker, you should be more precise on the excepted pattern... Do you want 3 numbers of 3 digits or something more restrictive on the numbers?

Comment: Please post what you have tried and how it fails.

Comment: @Mindbreaker its not a date format, its a two digit number separated by (-). Has the user starts entering number after two digits (-) must come then again after two digits(-) and more two. it should not accept more than this digits.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern i think it should be `^\d{2}(-\d{2}){2}$`. I tested it at [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) and it seems to work.